# проблема с re. Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

У меня имеется текст:

```
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sessionID"

596a2f350ffccdcab68e5408
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

profileSave
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_1_title"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_1_url"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_2_title"

-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_2_url"

-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_3_title"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_3_url"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="personaName"

name
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="real_name"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customURL"

url
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country"

RU
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="state"

-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="city"

-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="summary"

dsgsdfg
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

profileSave
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sessionID"

596a2f350ffccdcab68e6308
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

1
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671--
```

код программы:

```
import re

file = open('parse.txt', 'r')
# file_save = open('res.txt', 'w')
text = file.read()

regex = r"^(\n{2}|\n\w+)"

finalT = re.findall(regex, text)

print(finalT)
```

Но выводиться пустой массив.

на сайте regex101.com подсвечивается что мне нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: На regex101.com у вас `re.findall(regex, text, re.M)`. Пользуйтесь ссылкой ***Code Generator***, там весь  код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы могли бы обратить внимание, что на сайте `regex101` по умолчанию выставлены некоторые флаги: `gm`, т.е. global, multiline. Что касается первого, то он в `Pyhton`, кажется, по умолчанию и так есть, а вот multiline нужно выставить вручную:

```
finalT = re.findall(regex, text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Вывод на ваших данных:

```
['\n596a2f350ffccdcab68e5408', '\nprofileSave', '\n\n', '\n\n', '\n\n', '\n\n', '\nname', '\n\n', '\nurl', '\nRU', '\ndsgsdfg', '\nprofileSave', '\n596a2f350ffccdcab68e6308', '\n1']
```